# JavaScript - numeric data vs NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery, numeric

I'm sure I'm contravening some deep dark law of javascript, but I'm not really a JS developer and this is driving me mad. This function is called on an orderform to read the quantity and price of items, row by row, and then provide the subtotal, delivery and total.

The problem is with line 10 - it keeps "forgetting" that the variable data throughout is numeric (floating point) and so returns lots of NaN. How can I force the variables throughout this function to behave as numbers rather than strings?

**EDIT**

Here's the revised code based on feedback so far (thank you!). It's still not working ;)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function subTotal(rows) {
    var i, subTotal, lineTotal, orderShip, orderTotal;
    for (i = 1; i <= rows; ++i) {
        //Grab values from form
        var quantity = parseFloat($('#quantity' + i).val());
        var uPrice = parseFloat($('#uPrice' + i).val());

        //Error checking
        alert('quantity = ' + quantity +' and uPrice = ' + uPrice);
        if (isNaN(quantity)) alert('quantity = NaN');
        if (isNaN(uPrice)) alert('uPrice = NaN');

        if ((quantity == '') || (uPrice == '')) {
        } else {
            lineTotal = quantity * uPrice;
            alert('lineTotal = ' + lineTotal);
            subTotal += lineTotal;
            alert('subTotal = ' + subTotal);
        }
        //If we've maxed out the number of rows, then subTotal should be calculated - push back to form.
        if (i == rows) { 
            $('#orderSubTotal').val(subTotal );
            orderShip = subTotal * 0.25;
            $('#orderShip').val(orderShip.toFixed(2));
            orderTotal = subTotal + orderShip;
            $('#orderTotal').val(orderTotal.toFixed(2));
        }
    }
}
</script>

<form>
<table>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" id="item1" name="item1" value="Some description" readonly="readonly" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="quantity1" name="quantity1" value="25" onchange="javascript:subTotal('2')" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="uPrice1" name="uPrice1" value="1.50" readonly="readonly" /></td>    
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" id="item2" name="item2" value="Some description" readonly="readonly" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="quantity2" name="quantity2" value="25" onchange="javascript:subTotal('2')" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="uPrice2" name="uPrice2" value="2.75" readonly="readonly" /></td>    
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="3">
      SubTotal 
      <input type="text" id="orderSubTotal" name="orderSubTotal" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: right" value="0.00" />
      <br />Shipping 
      <input type="text" id="orderShip" name="orderShip" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: right" value="0.00" />
      <br />Total 
      <input type="text" id="orderTotal" name="orderTotal" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: right" value="0.00" />    
    </td>  
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: We can't possibly answer this without knowing what values you're supplying for `uPrice` and `quantity`. JavaScript will never 'forget' that values are numeric and arbitrarily decide to make them NaN.

Comment: Are you sure that all values uses . as the floating point separator?

Comment: Calling "parseFloat()" on something that's a result of a "*" operator (the "lineTotal") is never going to make any sense.

Comment: Talking about sense, using ordinary `for (var i = 0; i <= rows; i++)` will also make more of it. :)

Comment: yeah sorry - this code was the result of frustrated debugging - there were a few stabs in the dark. It was also a bit simplified from what I'm actually using so I forgot to remove the "x" etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the **real** problem is in your loop: You're looping from `0` to `rows` **inclusive**. So if you pass in `10` for `rows`, you'll be looping 11 times, starting with `0` and continuing through (including) `10`. I suspect that's your real problem. If you don't have a `quantity0` element, or (assuming `rows` is `10`) you don't have a `quantity10` element, then `$("#quantity" + i).val()` will return `undefined`, which converts to `NaN` when you convert it (implicitly or explicitly). (And the same for `uPrice0` / `uPrice10`.) And of course, once you have `NaN`, **any** mathematical operation using it results in `NaN`.

In terms of your question about how to ensure they don't change, basically, convert them to numbers early. You're currently using `quantity` and `uPrice` without converting them, which means initially they're strings. Now, JavaScript is pretty smart about converting them for you, but sometimes you want to be explicit.

Separately: Where does `x` come from?

You haven't shown any data to work with, but just speculatively:

```
function subTotal(rows) {
    var i, subTotal, lineTotal, quantity, uPrice, orderShip, orderTotal;

    subTotal = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
    // OR
    //for (i = 1; i <= rows; ++i) {
        quantity = $('#quantity' + i).val();
        uPrice = $('#uPrice' + i).val();
        if ((quantity == '') || (uPrice == '')) {
        } else {
            quantity = parseFloat(quantity);
            uPrice   = parseFloat(uPrice);
            // Might consider checking isNaN(quantity) and isNan(uPrice) here
            lineTotal = quantity * uPrice;
            subTotal += lineTotal;
            alert('subtotal = ' + subTotal);
        }
        if (i == x) {                           // Where does `x` come from?
            $('#orderSubTotal').val(subTotal );
            orderShip = subTotal * 0.25;
            $('#orderShip').val(orderShip.toFixed(2));
            orderTotal = subTotal + orderShip;
            $('#orderTotal').val(orderTotal.toFixed(2));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: True - I've revised the code based more on actually what I'm looking to achieve (and less on frustrated debugging), but there is still something not right here..

Comment: @hfidgen: Your new code (and sadly mine above; that was a bug; fixed) isn't setting `subTotal` to an initial value, hence it's undefined, which means (you guessed it) any numeric operation on it will be `NaN`. Adding `subTotal = 0;` at the top fixes it: http://jsbin.com/omuru3/2

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're performing a mathematical calculation on the fields before using `parseFloat`:

```
var lineTotal = quantity * uPrice;   // <-- result is most likely NaN here
subTotal = parseFloat(subTotal ) + parseFloat(lineTotal);
```

Perform your parsing at the point you get the values to make life a little easier:

```
    var quantity = parseFloat($('#quantity' + i).val());
    var uPrice = parseFloat($('#uPrice' + i).val());
```

Then change the `subTotal =` line to this:

```
        subTotal += lineTotal;
```

Another possible issue is if the result of `$('#uPrice' + i).val()` doesn't start with a parseable float — if it starts with a currency symbol, e.g. `£` or `$`, for instance — `parseFloat` will always return `NaN` for that field.  You can work around it using `$('#uPrice' + i).val().slice(1)`.

Comment: *"The problem is that you're performing a mathematical calculation on the fields before using `parseFloat`"* Actually, that part should work, since `*` will convert strings to numbers anyway: http://jsbin.com/apiya6

Comment: @TJC: not if the fields end with a string, e.g. `1x` or `5.00USD` - `parseFloat` would be required in these cases.  All we can do is speculate without input samples, which is why I also wrote the bottom part of my answer.

Comment: Okay, fair 'nuff, if they have trailing chars.

Answer (score 1):

Do some error checking:

```
function subTotal(rows) {
    var subTotal = 0;
    while (var i=0; i < rows; i++) {
        // convert as soon as you get the values
        var quantity = parseFloat($('#quantity' + i).val());
        var uPrice = parseFloat($('#uPrice' + i).val());
        if (isNaN(quantity) || isNaN(uPrice)) { // error checking
            alert("Invalid values on row " + i);
            continue;
        }
        var lineTotal = quantity * uPrice;
        subTotal += lineTotal;
        alert('subtotal = ' + subTotal);
        if (i == x) {
            $('#orderSubTotal').val(subTotal );
            var orderShip = subTotal * 0.25;
            $('#orderShip').val(orderShip.toFixed(2));
            var orderTotal = subTotal + orderShip;
            $('#orderTotal').val(orderTotal.toFixed(2));
        }
    }
}
```

You're probably running into an index problem at some point, getting a `NaN` from one of the (non-existing fields), adding it to `subTotal` which makes it a `NaN` instantly.

Answer (score 0):

You *better* convert the value **before** doing any mathematical operation. So the code should be:

```
var numQuanitity = parseFloat(quantity);
var numPrice = parseFloat(uPrice);
if (isNaN(numQuanitity) || isNaN(numPrice)) {
   //you can alert or ignore
}
else {
   var lineTotal = numQuanitity * numPrice;
   subTotal += lineTotal;
   alert('subtotal = ' + subTotal);
}
...
```

Comment: *"You must convert before doing any mathematical operation"* Not necessarily, JavaScript's smart about doing it for you. I'm not saying you *shouldn't*, just that "must" is overstating it. :-)

Comment: @T.J true, but I like to play it safe: when you're doing it yourself you can rest assured it will behave as you want it to behave. :-)